# How to find the PDF of a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Y is a uniform continuous random variable between [0,L] and X is a uniform continuous random variable given Y=y between [0,y]. What is the PDF of Z = X/Y.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to find CDF, P(Z<=z) and put Z = X/Y, then try to find CDF, differentiate to get PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to find the joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$

You know:

1. Marginal $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{L}\mathbb{1}_{[0;L]}(y)$$
2. Conditional $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{1}{y}\mathbb{1}_{[0;y]}(x)$$

So your joint density is

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{yL}\mathbb{1}_{[0;L]}(y)\mathbb{1}_{[0;y]}(x)$$

....now you can proceed as you explained...please post  you efforts

EDIT:

First observe that $z \in [0;1]$

Theb, using the definition of CDF you get

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z \leq z]=\mathbb{P}[Y >\frac{X}{z}]=$$

$$=\int_0^{Lz}dx\int_{\frac{X}{z}}^L \frac{1}{Ly}dy...$$

Some intermediate results:

$$\frac{1}{L}\int_0^{Lz}dx[ln y]_{\frac{x}{z}}^L=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^{Lz}[lnL-ln(x/z)]dx=...=zln L-(lnL-1)z=z$$

Note: the integral $\int_0^{Lz}ln(x/z)dx$ is solved by parts.

Comment: I have found the joint already but what to do with it since Z = X/Y is uniform in [0,1]

Comment: I updated my previous answer....now you must be able to finish by yourself

Comment: This integral is giving me the problem for the last 3 hours that is why I put it here on stack. y integral gives ln|L| - ln|x/z| now when I integrate with respect to x it become undefined.

Comment: I updated my answer with some intermediate calculation.. Z is uniform in [0;1]

Comment: Thank you very much, its z, I got it. Actually its a square of length L. I identify the upper half of the square through CDF, correctly found the limits of double integral. The problem was solving the integral. Thanks tommik humbly obliged.

Comment: Just by inspection, $X\mid Y~\sim\mathcal U[0..Y]$ clearly entails that the ratio $\tfrac XY$ will be uniformly distributed over $[0{..}1]$,  *independent* of whatever value $Y$ may realise.